# Is There Any Way to Auto Increase Data Field Variable ($NUM) in gawk?

Tags: linux, gawk

I have a pipe delimited file that contains many data fields. I am trying to use gawk separate them. The log likes this:

```
United States|San Francisco|CA|...goes on...
Germany|Quebec City|Quebec|...goes on...
```

The output format would look like:

```
Country: United States
City: San Francisco
State: CA
...goes on...
```

The question is...is there any way I can auto increase $1 all the way to $15? Skip $16 then auto increase again? I just don't want to hard code my gawk script with this:

```
print "Country:\t", $1
print "City:\t", $2
print "State:\t", $3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop and an if condition:

```
awk -v FS='|' '
   BEGIN{split("country;city;state",a,";")}
   {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if (i != 16) print a[i],i}' input
```

Comment: Why not split the loop up since only one field is being skipped? This removes the if statement, which allows for faster processing (in theory).

Comment: great solution, a split function and a for loop takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear, but if your truncated input looks something like:

```
United States|San Francisco|CA|Salem|OR...
```

and you are just trying to enumerate city/state pairs, you can certainly do:

```
for( i = 2; i <= NF ;i+=2 ) {
  print "City:\t", $i
  print "State:\t", $(i+1)
}
```

Comment: I am NOT trying to enumerate through city/state pairs. I want it to list 15 of data fields out in this format: NAME:\t, $i. Then I want to skip 16, then auto increase again. I guess a function will have to created since every line as different string starting out?

Comment: Where do the names come from?  Are they in the first line of the file?  It sounds like you want a for loop, skipping the 16th iteration.

Comment: No, names are not the first line of the file. A documentation explains each field